# Migrate birt from version 4.4 to 4.9. The resource path [ /…/…]has been normalized to null which is not valid

Tags: java, eclipse, migration, birt, birt-deapi

Error migrate birt 4.4 to 4.9
I have a problem when running a report where when opening the layout it is giving a

“The resource path [ /…/…]has been normalized to null which is not valid”

Do you have any idea what it could be?

I put the part of the source that the error happens and the error itself.

Src:

```java
    InputStream fileLayout = new 
    ByteArrayInputStream(EntityUtils.toByteArray(methodLayoutReport.getEntity()));

    String reportEnder = servlet.getRealPath("Report/include/glw/view/report") + "/" + reportName
    + ".rptdesign";

    design = birtReportEngine.openReportDesign(reportEnder, fileLayout);//line error
```

ERROR:

```java
INFO: Server startup in [23135] milliseconds
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [/WEB-INF/classes/…/…/…/…/estrutura/est_report_library_base.rptlibrary] has been normalized to [null] which is not valid
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:954)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1078)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.util.ResourceLocatorImplBase.tryFragmentSearch(ResourceLocatorImplBase.java:289)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.util.ResourceLocatorImplBase.getResource(ResourceLocatorImplBase.java:179)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.util.ResourceLocatorImplBase.findResource(ResourceLocatorImplBase.java:80)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.core.ModuleImpl.findResource(ModuleImpl.java:1181)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.IncludedLibrariesStructureListState$IncludedLibraryStructureState.end(IncludedLibrariesStructureListState.java:99)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.util.XMLParserHandler.endElement(XMLParserHandler.java:177)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.ModuleReader.readModule(ModuleReader.java:94)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.DesignReader.read(DesignReader.java:81)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.core.DesignSessionImpl.openDesign(DesignSessionImpl.java:293)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.SessionHandleImpl.openDesign(SessionHandleImpl.java:257)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.SessionHandle.openDesign(SessionHandle.java:1)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.parser.ReportParser.getDesignHandle(ReportParser.java:136)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.getReportDesignHandle(ReportEngineHelper.java:211)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.openReportDesign(ReportEngineHelper.java:223)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.openReportDesign(ReportEngineHelper.java:156)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngine.openReportDesign(ReportEngine.java:307)
at br.com.ipm.report.servlet.WebReport.doPost(WebReport.java:93)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that as I was passing a relative path of the library in the report, it was trying to take the root path of the project, and as my root was "/WEB-INF/classes" there was no way to go back more than two levels, generating the error, thanks for the help. I'm kinda new to some things

Comment: This is what I meant with a).

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess:
This might be caused by

a) security enhancements to avoid access to arbitrary files
b) Incorrect setting of the resource path

Note that the error occurs when the report (or an intermediate library) tries to open the library `est_report_library_base.rptlibrary`.
This means that the report itself was successfully found.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that the problem is in the library, I even tested removing it from XML, but I can't stay if I use this library. I use by default in my reports the path "…/…/…/…/structure/est_report_library_base.rptlibrary", which says where the base library is, but in my tests on birt 4.9 I noticed that if I put a random path like ". ./../aaa/estrutura/est_report_library_base.rptlibrary" this error is not generated, or even leaving only "…/…/estrutura/est_report_library_base.rptlibrary", but when I put "../../../. ./structure/est_report_library_base.rptlibrary" error is generated.

Comment: Report path: "C:\projects\workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\webreport\Report\include\glw\view\report" Library path: "C:\projects\workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\webreport\Report\structure\est_report_library_base.rptlibrary"